# For a Borel function when does there exist a set of full measure with measurable image

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a standard Borel probability space. Consider a measurable and measure preserving self map $f:X\to X$. We [know](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133178/the-image-of-a-measurable-set-under-a-measurable-function) that $f(A)$ is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) for any $A\in \Sigma$, but this does not necessarily mean that $f(A)$ is Borel measurable.

> What are the weakest conditions we can impose on $X$ or $f$ to ensure the existence of some $A\in \Sigma$, such that $f(A)\in \Sigma$ and $\mu(A)=1$?

I say weakest, because we know that if $f$ is injective then $X$ would suffice (because if the complement of an analytic set is analytic then it is Borel).

EDIT: Michael's comment gives a very useful approach. I think surjectivity is still quite a strong condition, but if there was a weaker condition we could impose ensuring that the image contains a measurable set of full measure that would be grand.

Comment: It holds if $f$ is surjective, measure-preserving, and there is a measurable set $B \subseteq X$ such that $\mu(B)=1$. This holds immediately by defining $A = f^{-1}(B)$ and noting $f(A)=B$ by surjectivity.  More generally, we can remove surjectivity if we can find a measurable subset $C$ of the _image_ of $f$ (i.e., $C \subseteq f(X)$) such that $\mu(C)=1$.

Comment: @Michael I had realized my question was too open, so commented just as I was editing my answer to mention the simpler cases I already knew about. Thank you though, I had forgotten to mention your comment in the edit anyway

Comment: Shouldn't simply demanding that $f$ be Borel (i.e. the pre-images of open sets are Borel) be enough?

Comment: @K.Power : Not clear why you want to ignore my condition.  The general condition I give is both necessary and sufficient in the case when $f(X)$ is measurable.

Comment: @Michael I don't want to ignore it! I just didn't think to include it in the edit as it is the first comment. Sorry if that was the impression I gave. I am actually very interested in your comment. I would be very happy knowing of a condition ensuring there is a measurable $C$ of full measure contained in the image.

Comment: @NotMike It would be great if that were true, but I cannot think of a proof or counterexample.

Comment: @Michael The definition of probability measure I have in mind means that $\mu(X)=1$. That might be causing some confusion

Comment: @NotMike The first line of [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-03/S0002-9939-1961-0131508-X/S0002-9939-1961-0131508-X.pdf) paper implies that for a counterexample we would need to consider a function that isn't even countable to one to find a counterexample.

Comment: I'm confused, you want the forward image of a Borel measure one set to be measurable correct?

Comment: @NotMike  yes, that would ensure the existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general case (for possibly incomplete measure spaces). Recall that Property P is defined in my other answer.

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be the original measure space.  Let $(X, \Sigma_c, \mu_c)$ be the completed measure space. Note that $\mu(B)=\mu_c(B)$ for all $B \in \Sigma$.

#### Claim:

Property P holds if and only if $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$.

To prove the claim we first have some lemmas.

#### Lemma 1:

Every element of $\Sigma_c$ can be written as $R \cup H$ where $R \in \Sigma$ and $H$ is a subset of a measure-0 set in $\Sigma$.

Proof:  (see wikipedia for this lemma here): 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure

#### Lemma 2:

If $f$ is measurable and measure-preserving under $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, then it is also measurable and measure-preserving under $(X, \Sigma_c, \mu_c)$.

Proof:  Let $S \in \Sigma_c$.  We want to show $f^{-1}(S) \in \Sigma_c$ and $\mu_c(f^{-1}(S)) = \mu_c(S)$.

We know $S= R \cup H$ for $R \in \Sigma$ and $H \subseteq Z$ for some $Z \in \Sigma$ with $\mu(Z)=0$.  So 
$$f^{-1}(S) = f^{-1}(R \cup H) = f^{-1}(R) \cup f^{-1}(H) \quad (*) $$
But $f^{-1}(H) \subseteq f^{-1}(Z)$ and $\mu(f^{-1}(Z))=\mu(Z)=0$ by the measure-preserving property.  So $f^{-1}(H)$ is a subset of a measure zero set and so $f^{-1}(H) \in \Sigma_c$.  Also, $f^{-1}(R) \in \Sigma \subseteq \Sigma_c$. Thus, (*) shows that $f^{-1}(S)$ is the union of two sets in $\Sigma_c$, so $f^{-1}(S) \in \Sigma_c$.

Next, note that since $S = R \cup H$ with $\mu_c(H)=0$, we know 
$$\mu_c(S)=\mu_c(R) \quad (**) $$

On the other hand, since (*  ) writes $f^{-1}(S)$ as the union of two sets in $\Sigma_c$ we get:
\begin{align}
\mu_c(f^{-1}(S))  &\overset{(a)}{\leq}  \mu_c(f^{-1}(R)) + \mu_c(f^{-1}(H)) \\
&\overset{(b)}{\leq} \mu_c(f^{-1}(R)) + \mu_c(f^{-1}(Z)) \\
&\overset{(c)}{=} \mu(f^{-1}(R)) + \mu(f^{-1}(Z))\\
&\overset{(d)}{=} 
\mu(R) + \mu(Z) \\
&\overset{(e)}{=} \mu(R) + 0 \\
&\overset{(f)}{=} \mu_c(R)  \\
&\overset{(g)}{=} \mu_c(S)  
\end{align}
where (a) holds by (*); (b) holds because $H\subseteq Z$; (c) holds because $R$ and $Z$ are both in $\Sigma$; (d) holds because $f$ is measure-preserving in the original measure space; (e) holds because $\mu(Z)=0$; (f) holds because $R \in \Sigma$; (g) holds by (**).
$\Box$

Proof of claim that  Property P holds if and only if $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$:

Proof ($\Longrightarrow$): Suppose Property P holds.  Then there is a set $A$ such that $A \in \Sigma$, $\mu(A)=1$, and $f(A) \in \Sigma$.  Since every element of $\Sigma$ is also in $\Sigma_c$, and $1=\mu(A)=\mu_c(A)$, it follows that property P holds in the completed measure space.  Since $f$ is measurable and measure-preserving in the completed measure space, and since property P holds in the completed measure space, by Claim 2 in my previous answer it follows that $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$. $\Box$

Proof ($\Longleftarrow$): Suppose $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$.  Then $f(X) = R \cup H$ where $R \in \Sigma$ and $H\subseteq Z$ where $Z \in \Sigma$ and $\mu(Z)=0$.  Then $\mu_c(H)=0$ and so $\mu_c(f(X)) = \mu_c(R) = \mu(R)$.

However, we have $f^{-1}(f(X)) = X$, and since $f$ is measure-preserving in the completed measure space we have
$$1=\mu(X)=\mu_c(X) = \mu_c(f^{-1}(f(X)) = \mu_c(f(X)) =  \mu(R)$$
So define $A = f^{-1}(R)$.  Since $R \in \Sigma$ and $f$ is measurable, we know $A \in \Sigma$.  Since $f$ is measure-preserving we know $\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(R))=\mu(R)=1$. Finally, we know $f(A)=R \in \Sigma$. Thus, Property P holds in the original measure space. 
(To show that $f(A)=R$ note that $f(A) = f(f^{-1}(R)) \subseteq R$.  However, since $R\subseteq f(X)$, every element of $R$ can be mapped to by $f$, so $f(f^{-1}(R))=R$.) $\Box$

Comment: This is a really nice answer, thank you for the effort. I don't have time to digest the subtleties of your proofs today, but soon as I do I'll accept it, as I don't think I can hope for a more general answer to the question. This is a really nice characterization for property P.

Comment: Thanks.  If I had time I'd optimize the proof.  Some basic facts that are important in the proof are: a) If $W = U \cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are measurable and $\mu(V)=0$, then $W$ is measurable and $\mu(W)=\mu(U)$. b) For any set $X$, any function $f:X\rightarrow X$, any $B \subseteq X$, we have: (i) $f^{-1}(f(B)) \supseteq B$; (ii) $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$; (iii) If $B \subseteq  f(X)$ then $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$.

Comment: My previous answer has examples of: (i) An incomplete space such that $f(X) \notin \Sigma$, but property P holds (which of course means $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$ by the above claim); (ii) A complete  space (so $\Sigma=\Sigma_c$) such that $f(X) \notin \Sigma$ (which of course means Property P does not hold by the above claim).  Now for the Borel space, it is incomplete, although it is difficult to find an example where $f(X) \notin \Sigma$ because non-Borel sets are difficult to construct. I would expect the image of “typical” functions to be in $\Sigma$ (or at least in $\Sigma_c$).

Comment: The following reference suggests that if $f$ is (Borel) measurable then $f(X)$ is Lebesgue measurable.  I cannot verify that. However, since (I think) the Lebesgue measure is the completion of the Borel measure, if the link is true it would imply that for the Borel space we have $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$ _always_, and so Property P holds _always_ (that makes my examples in the other answer more important, as they are not Borel examples). https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133178/the-image-of-a-measurable-set-under-a-measurable-function

Comment: I believe that your reference is is correct, as I remember seeing something like that in the book *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Kechris. The fact that property P holds for all Borel sets is really quite nice. It seems that it might simplify some things in ergodic theory. Such as showing a map is a factor map.

Comment: Well, if any of these ideas are publishable you can let me know.

Comment: I'm just a lowly pre-thesis Master's student, so I wouldn't hold your breath, but if by some fortuitous chance I realise that there is something publishable in here I'll definitely let you know.

Answer (score 1):

My comments above assumed a general measure space with $\mu(X)$ not necessarily 1. The case $\mu(X)=1$ is a bit easier.

Assume:

- $X$ is a measure space with sigma algebra $\Sigma$ and measure $\mu$.
- $\mu(X)=1$
- $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a measurable and measure-preserving function.

#### Definition:

Let's say that *Property P* holds if there is a set $A \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(A)=1$ and $f(A) \in \Sigma$.

#### Claim 1:

Suppose $f(X) \in \Sigma$.  Then Property P holds.

Proof: Define $A=X$.  Then $A \in \Sigma$, $\mu(A)=1$, and $f(A) = f(X) \in \Sigma$. So Property P holds.  $\Box$

#### Claim 2:

Suppose the sigma algebra is *complete*, so that all subsets of measure-0 sets also have measure 0. Then Property P holds if and only if $f(X) \in \Sigma$.

Proof ($\Longleftarrow$): Suppose $f(X) \in \Sigma$.  Then Claim 1 ensures Property P holds. $\Box$.

Proof ($\Longrightarrow$): Suppose Property P holds. Let $A$ be a set such that $A \in \Sigma$, $\mu(A)=1$, $f(A)\in \Sigma$. We know: 
$$ A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)) \quad (*)   $$
and since $f(A)$ is measurable we have $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is measurable and 
$$ 1= \mu(A) \overset{(a)}{\leq} \mu(f^{-1}(f(A))) \overset{(b)}= \mu(f(A))  \overset{(c)}{\leq} 1$$
where (a) holds by (*); (b) holds by the measure-preserving property of $f$; (c) holds because $f(A) \subseteq X$ and $\mu(X)=1$. It follows that $\mu(f(A))=1$ and so
$$ \mu(f(A)^c) = 0$$
But $f(X)^c \subseteq f(A)^c$ and so $\mu(f(X)^c)=0$ (by completeness).  Thus, $f(X)^c \in \Sigma$ and so $f(X)\in \Sigma$. $\Box$

---

#### Examples

1) If we use $X=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $\Sigma = \{\phi, X, \{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\} \}$, $f(1)=f(2)=2, f(3)=f(4)=4$, $\mu(\{1,2\})=\mu(\{3,4\})=1/2$, then $\mu(X)=1$, $f$ is measurable and measure-preserving, this is a complete measure space, but Property P does not hold because $f(X) = \{2, 4\} \notin \Sigma$.

2) Same $X$ and $\Sigma$ as before, but define $f:X\rightarrow X$ by $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=4, f(4)=4$.  Define $\mu(\{1,2\})=1, \mu(\{3,4\})=0$.  This is a non-complete measure space with $\mu(X)=1$, $f$ is measurable and measure-preserving, and Property P holds with respect to the set $A = \{1, 2\}$. However, $f(X)$ is not measurable.

Now, if we complete the measure by adding the null sets $\{3\}$ and $\{4\}$ to $\Sigma$, then indeed $f(X)$ is measurable with measure 1.

Comment: My other answer extends this to show that Property P holds if and only if $f(X) \in \Sigma_c$, where $\Sigma_c$ is the _completed measure space_.